# PHP returns the wrong value of a radio button

Tags: php, html, variables, radio-button

I have a problem with a radio button which has two values, `"po"` and `"jo"`, but PHP always returns the value `"on"`. How can I fix this?

This is code in the `.html` file:

```
    <label for="fangspotted">A e keni pare qenin tim Fang?</label>
    Po <input id="fangspotted" name="fangspotted" type="radio" values="po"/>
    Jo <input id="fangspotted" name="fangspotted" type="radio" values="jo"/><br/>
```

and this is in the `.php` file:

```
$fang_spotted = $_POST['fangspotted'];
```

Comment: The answers below are correct.  The W3C Validator is your friend.  The very first thing to do when "things HTML" do not work is to validate the HTML: http://validator.w3.org/  (There's a validator for CSS, too, and there are other HTML validators that some like better.)

Comment: Open the NET tab in Firebug (or the browser debugger of your choice). Observe that *on* is what's actually being posted to the server, so it's no surprise that that's what PHP gives you. Deduce that this is *not* a PHP error. Then put your page into a [validatior](http://validator.w3.org/ "W3C Validator") and observe that `values` is an invalid attribute. In other words, *learn to debug*.

Comment: Voting to close as it's a "spot the typo" sort of question which benefits no-one (except the OP who has their answer now anyhow ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The html attrib should be `value` not `values`

So:

```
<label for="fangspotted">A e keni pare qenin tim Fang?</label>
Po <input id="fangspotted" name="fangspotted" type="radio" value="po"/>
Jo <input id="fangspotted" name="fangspotted" type="radio" value="jo"/><br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

values error

```
values="po"
```

It should be

```
value="po"
```